# number + counter + して?

Tags: grammar

I came across "2人して" recently and am wondering about the function/translation of the "して" in this case. Is it maybe similar to "同士"? If someone could explain this usage to me I would appreciate it, thank you

Comment: More context would be helpful.

Comment: So it's simply an emphatic version of 2人で. It's used when "in a twosome" is important in conversation. There is no 3人して or 1人して at least in modern Japanese.